# How to automatically play a sound file after importing

Tags: import, sound

I want *Mathematica* (Version 11.0.1.0) to automatically play a specific sound file after importing from the hard drive without any user intervention other than opening the notebook. Here is what I have tried:

```
SetDirectory["D:\\MyTestDirectory"];
mysound = Import["Two_musical_notes_overlap-for-test.wav"];
EmitSound[mysound]
```

After that cell is evaluated I get a dialog box with a play button that the user has has to click on to get the "wav" file to play.  I do not want the user to have to do anything other than evaluate the cell which will cause the sound to be played.  It would be nice if I could even suppress the sound dialog box from even appearing but I'll be happy with just getting this to play automatically.

[image]

Comment: The observed behavior is due to that fact that in the current version, your sound file is automatically imported as an `Audio[]` object instead of as a `Sound[]` object. (It does sound confusing...)

Comment: Out of curiosity: what `$Version` are you using? 'Cause I have no problems with `s = Import[ "ExampleData/rule30.wav"];
EmitSound[s]` on `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

Comment: @J.M. it **sounds** confusing made my day.

Comment: @corey979 - I am using Mathematica 11.0.1.0.  The latest version.  I have modified my question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
f = Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav", "Sound"];
EmitSound[f]
```

This plays right away, when cell is evaluated. To make it play when notebook is opened, you might want to put it in initialization cell also.

Comment: Thank You @Nasser that worked perfectly.  I guess "Audio" object is different than a "Sound" object.

Comment: ``Sound`AudioToSound``?